# On duplicate key update with the new value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (bold=PK):

log:    [**id**,type, value]

totals:  [**type**,total]

Where the "total" value at "totals" is the sum of the values of all entries in the log with the same type. I want to update the totals table so I run a query:

```
INSERT INTO totals (type,total) (SELECT type,sum(value) AS total FROM log GROUP BY type)
```

This works fine except when the PK already exists, I'm trying to solve it adding a:

```
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total=XXXXXXXX
```

but I don't know what to put as XXXXXXXXX to refer the new value

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = VALUES(total)
```

Answer (score 2):

As Gordon already said, you use VALUES(`field`) to get the value that would be inserted, or just `field` to get the old value

```
INSERT INTO .... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `field` = VALUES(`field`)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

In your case - the complete query should look something like:

```
INSERT INTO totals (type,total) (SELECT type,sum(value) AS total FROM log GROUP BY type) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = VALUES(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand what do you want but:

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM log l WHERE l.type = type)
```